# Scala library available in both compile and test configuration

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a library that I wish to expose in both the unit tests in Scala and the code itself.

In sbt, I added my library dependency with configuration `"test"` and then it's available for tests but I cannot use it in the code. If I leave the configuration be or add `"compile"` it's not available to be imported in unit tests.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.14.0",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.6" % "test",
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.6" % "test")
```

The main problem is that I expose an abstract class I want to use all over the place in other code: `abstract class UnitSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with ScalaCHeckDrivenPropertyChecks` and also use in the tests of the library. If I add `"test"` to ScalaCheck it cannot find it in the main code of the library. If I leave it as is, it cannot from `org.scalatestplus.scalacheck.ScalaCheckDrivenPropertyChecks`. This used to be OK and work fine with 3.0.5 and `GeneratorDrivenProperyChecks` but that's been deprecated.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I tried `"test->compile"` but that also doesn't do what I had hoped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine configurations. In order to have a library both in compile and test you just add bot configurations.

```
// wrong: libraryDependencies += "<organization>" %% "<module>"  % "<version>" % "compile->compile" % "test->compile"
```

The syntax means roughly: *project configuration* dependsOn(->) *configuration of libraryDependency*.

**Update**

You can also add the dependency twice with different configurations.

```
libraryDependencies += "<organization>" %% "<module>"  % "<version>",
libraryDependencies += "<organization>" %% "<module>"  % "<version>" % "test"
```

**Update 2**

I think the syntax in the first example is not what I meant to provide.

```
libraryDependencies += "<organization>" %% "<module>"  % "<version>" % "compile->compile;test->compile"
```

At least that is what I use in my `libraryDependencies`.

Comment: When I do that I get `Configurations already specified for module org.scalacheck:scalacheck:1.14.0:compile->compile`. I also tried `% "compile" % "test"` but that gives me the same.

Comment: What does remote/local configuration mean in this context? I managed to get it working with a simple `"compile;test"` for the libraries that need to be in both. It did not work with the arrows.

Comment: I updated the answer with (hopefully) clearer wording. Imo the expanded syntax `compile->compile` is more expressive. However, you are right, one only really needs it if something more exotic is needed (e.g. if there are non standard configurations involved or someone would want to have `compile` depend on test code of a dependency 'compile->test' (weird, but happens).

Answer (score 0):

So you need a trait from the Scalatest JAR in non-test code. I am not sure why it worked before, but it would make sense to me just to remove `% "test"` from the scalatest dependency. That will make it available in `compile` and everything from `compile` is available in `test` too.

And for Scalactic I think the main use-case for it as a separate dependency is when you need it in `compile` but only use Scalatest in `test` (or don't use it at all). If they are both needed for tests only (or for compile), Scalatest will bring Scalactic with it.

> I tried "test->compile" but that also doesn't do what I had hoped...

`"test->compile"` is the same as `"test"`:

> > [A configuration without a mapping (no `"->"`) is mapped to `"default"` or `"compile"`. The `->` is only needed when mapping to a different configuration than those.](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Library-Management.html)